# Leibniz's rule for improper integrals (Fourier transform of a derivative)

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform

There is the following proof for the Fourier transform of a derivative:
$$
f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(\nu) e^{2\pi i \nu t}d\nu
$$
then
$$
f'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(\nu)e^{2\pi i \nu t} d\nu = 2\pi i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \nu S(\nu)e^{2\pi i \nu t}d\nu \longleftrightarrow 2\pi i\nu S(\nu)
$$

Why in the proof are we able to move a derivative inside the integral? It seems that we apply Leibniz's rule, but the integral is improper. Thank you for your help!

Comment: In general, you cannot just pull the derivative inside. You need some assumption like $x \mapsto x \cdot S (x) \in L^1$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thank you for the reply! So the proof is incorrect or we have some necessary conditions given that the original Fourier transform exists?

Comment: Your proof is incorrect since you cannot simply pull $\nu$ outside the integral. it should read $$f'(t) = 2\pi i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \nu S(\nu) e^{2\pi i \nu t} \, d\nu.$$ In order to interchange differentiability and integration you have to assume that $\nu \mapsto \nu S(\nu)$ is integrable, as PhoemueX pointed out.

Comment: @saz Thank you for the corrections, I updated the question!

Comment: @PhoemueX Why the assumption $xS(x)\in L_1$ is enough to move the derivative inside?

Comment: @Konstantin: My answer here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246380/difference-of-differentiation-under-integral-sign-between-lebesgue-and-riemann) explains this in some detail. Essentially, we want to apply the dominated convergence theorem and this can be justified if $x S(x) \in L^1$.