# Why is that $\int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)dt = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_a^b f(x,t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, chain-rule

> This question is concerned with the integral with parameter, so let's assume that every function below is smooth.
>
> To find the formula for the derivative of an integral with parameter, say $$g(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt$$ for some function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, one would define $$ F: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}, F(a,b,x) = \int_a^b f(x,t)dt $$ and then use the multivariable chain-rule to determine $g'$.

Thus, we would have that $$g'(x) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial a} \cdot \frac{\partial a}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial b} \cdot \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}.$$

It is easy so see that $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} \cdot \frac{\partial a}{\partial x} = -f(x,a(x)) \cdot a'(x)$$ and that $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial b} \cdot \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} = f(x,b(x)) \cdot b'(x). $$

What I don't understand is why we have that $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)dt. $$

Shouldn't it be $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_a^b f(x,t)dt ? $$

Could you please tell me why we are allowed to interchange the partial derivative and the integral?

Comment: By the way, this is the Leibniz rule (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: I don't know your background (e.g. do you know any measure theory) so I don't know which related question question to link you to, but this only works under certain conditions and is called "differentiation under the integral sign". See, for instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246380/26369

Comment: This is because $a$ and $b$ are assumed constant during differentiation with respect to $x$...

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)dt$$

and

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_a^b f(x,t)dt $$

are essentially the same thing in this context, although it's more often referred to as

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{d}{d x}\int_a^b f(x,t)dt= \int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)dt ?$$

As @MinusOne-Twelfth pointed out this is the Leibniz rule.